# Angular 2 Karma Unit Tests Cannot Find Name

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, webpack, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular 2 project set up that I wanted to add unit testing to using Karma, Jasmine, and Webpack. However, after setting things up I have an issue where the tests compile and run successfully, but the console output logs a ton of errors from TypeScript saying it can't find names for certain jasmine and es6 classes as shown below:

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out why this is occuring, as all the cases I've come across where people have had similar issues were using < TypeScript 2.0, so the issue was generally something with typings. In my case I'm running TypeScript 2.0.8 and have the typings using the new style via npm @types. Obviously the compiler is somehow correctly finding the types (since the unit tests do run fine after the errors) while still saying they do not exist. Has anyone had this issue before and know a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously the compiler is somehow correctly finding the types (since the unit tests do run fine after the errors)

That is incorrect. Actually the compiler is *not* finding them. It works fine because you have jasmine (JS) and es6-shim (JS) added to the karma runtime. It can't find the typings (hence the compile errors) but at runtime the JS files are present in the environment.

Make sure you have

1. Installed `@types/jasmine` and `@types/core-js`
2. Added the following to your `tsconfig.json - compilerOptions`

   ```
   "typeRoots": [
       "./node_modules/@types/"
   ]

   // works for me without it, but maybe also
   "types": [
       "jasmine",
       "core-js"
   ]
   ```

Comment: Good to know about what files it can/can't find. However, those two types are already installed via npm and I already have the typeRoots and types properties set as indicated.

Comment: I'm not sure then.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: After getting some sleep, I approached it again this morning and found out that I had the types array in a different position in tsconfig, outside of compilerOptions. Thank you for indicating that the config needed to be in the compilerOptions part.